# Deleting XML node with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to simply save an XML file from the web locally (this part works fine) and then delete a node of the XML and resave it. However, the local xml file ends up blank when I do the following:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($xmlurl);
file_put_contents('187file.xml', $xml);
$rep187 = simplexml_load_file('187file.xml');
unset($rep187->ComparableSalesReport->ComparableSales->ComparableSale);
file_put_contents('187file.xml', $rep187);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) does not accept an object as the second argument (it only accepts a string, an array or a stream resource).

You can pass a string instead by using [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) on your `$rep187` document, like so:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($xmlurl);
file_put_contents('187file.xml', $xml);
$rep187 = simplexml_load_file('187file.xml');
unset($rep187->ComparableSalesReport->ComparableSales->ComparableSale);
file_put_contents('187file.xml', $rep187->asXML());
```